# PHP MySQL Select * from 2 different tables and display the merged data

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have two tables one called 'user' and the other called 'user_info'.

user;

```
userid       |      username
------------------------------
1            |      mary
2            |      john
3            |      liam
```

user_info;

```
userid       |      desc
----------------------------------------------------
1            |      hello, my name is mary i am 26
2            |      message me if you need any help
3            |      please leave me alone
```

I want to display the corrosponding description from the 'user_info' table with the information from the 'user' table based on the userID. So that it will appear like:

```
Name: John
UserID: 2
Description: message me if you need any help
```

Here is my code;

```
//Query the database
$resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user,user_info");

//Count the returned rows
if ($resultSet->num_rows != 0) {


//Turn the results into an ArrayAccess
while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
{
    $uid = $rows['UserID'];
    $username = $rows['username'];
    $desc = $rows['desc'];

echo "<p>Name: $username </p>
      <p>User ID: $uid </p>
      <p>Description: $desc </p>
      <hr>";
}
```

Currently it returns as many different combinations as it can; like so:

```
Name:Mary
UserID:1
Description:hello, my name is mary i am 26
--------------------------------------------
Name:John
UserID:1
Description:message me if you need any help
--------------------------------------------
Name:Liam
UserID:1
Description:please leave me alone
--------------------------------------------
Name:Mary
UserID:2
Description:hello, my name is mary i am 26
--------------------------------------------
Name:John
UserID:2
Description:message me if you need any help
--------------------------------------------
ETC...
```

How can I make it so that it only returns the correct corresponding data based on the userID (only once) so that it displays all the users with their correct username, id and description?

I wasn't sure how else to explain this, if anyone would like me to further elaborate I have no problem trying again,

Comment: use join, select * from x left join y where x.user_id=y.userid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your request

```
$resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user 
    JOIN user_info ON user_info.userid = user.userid");
```

Comment: Perfect! This answered my question! Thank you for your help! New to php so still learning! :)

Comment: Also just realised that I had this written down somewhere! It's always right under your nose!! Anyway congratulations on hitting 800!

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying you query as below:

```
SELECT user.*,user_info.desc FROM user INNER JOIN user_info ON user.userid=user_info.userid;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Make an Inner Join Query like this:

```
Select userId, userName, desc from user inner join user_info on
user.userid = user_info.userid
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use join method to get data from different tables according to their relationship, as per as your problem query would be like this,

```
select user.username as Name, user.userid as UserID, user_info.desc as Description from user inner join user_info on user.userid=user_info.userid;
```